# AWS pg_dump Does Not Include Globals

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

We have multiple PostgreSQL Instances in AWS RDS.  We need to maintain an on-premise copy of each database to comply with our disaster recovery policy.  I have been successful is using pg_dump and pg_restore to export the database schemas and tables to our on-premise server, but I have been unsuccessful in exporting the roles and tablespaces.  I have found that this is only possible by using pg_dumpall, but as this requires super_user access, and that is not allowed in RDS, how can I export those aspects of the database to on our on-premise server?

My pg_dump command:

```
Pg_dump -h {AWS Endpoint} -U {Master Username}-p 5432 -F c -f C:\AWS_Backups\{filename}.dmp {database name}
```

My pg_restore command:

```
pg_restore -h {AWS Endpoint} -p 5432 -U {Master Username} -d {database name} {filename}.dmp
```

I have found multiple examples of people using pg_dump to export their PostgreSQL databases, however, they are not addressing the "Globals" that are ignored using pg_dump.  Have I misread the documentation?  After performing my pg_restore, my logins were not created on the database.

Any help you can provide on getting the *FULL* database (including globals) to our offsite location would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pg_dump` never includes globals. You need to use `pg_dumpall` with the `--globals-only` option.

Comment: That's what I've found, however, that is not an option in AWS, as it requires super_user access.  When I attempt to run pg_dumpall, I receive the error "permission denied for relation pg_authid".  Has anyone been able to get around that AWS limitation?

Comment: I think that's by design, not an AWS limitation. I could be wrong.

Comment: The AWS limitation is not allowing the role of super_user to exist and execute pg_dumpall, not that pg_dumpall requires super_user access.  What I'm trying to determine is how can I copy all of the roles/logins and tablespaces from AWS RDS PostreSQL instance to my on-premise PostgreSQL database copy?

Comment: If the roles, logins, tablespaces, and everything else were under version control, and you treated version control as the single point of truth, you could just load them from version control.

Comment: Hi Mike.  Wouldn't you have to us pg_dump (or similar) to get the database out of AWS and into version control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an answer to my question anywhere online. Just in case someone else may be experiencing this problem, I thought I would post a high-level outline of my "solution". I go around my elbow to get to my knee, but this is the option I have come up with:

1. Create a table (I created 2 - 1 for roles, and one for logins) in each PostgreSQL database within AWS. This table(s) will need to have all columns that you will need to dynamically create the SQL to do CREATE, GRANT, REVOKE, etc.
2. Insert all roles, logins, privileges, and permissions into this table. These are scattered everywhere, but here are the ones I used:

   - pg_auth_members (role and login relationships)
   - pg_roles (role and login permissions ie can login, inherit parent, etc)
   - information_schema.role_usage_grants (schema privileges)
   - information_schema.role_table_grants (table privileges)
   - information_schema.role_routine_grants (function privileges)
3. To fill in the gaps, there are clever queries on the web page below to use the built in functions to check for access. You will have to loop through the tables and process a row at a time

   - https://vibhorkumar.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/list-user-privileges-in-postgresqlppas-9-1/
   - Specifically, I used a variation of database_privs function
4. Once all of the data is in those tables, you can execute pg_dump, and it will extract that info from each database to your on-premise location. I did this through a Python script.
5. On your server, use the data in the tables to dynamically create the SQL statements needed to run the CREATE, GRANT, REVOKE, etc. scripts. Save in a .sql file that you can instruct a Python script to execute against the database and recreate the AWS roles and logins.
6. One thing I forgot to mention - because we are unable to access the pg_auth_id table in AWS, I have found no way to extract the passwords out of AWS. We are going to store these in a password manager, and when I create the CREATE ROLE statements, I'll pass a default to be updated.

I haven't completed the process, but it has taken me several days to track down a viable option to the absence of pg_dumpall's functionality. If anyone sees any flaws in my logic, or has a better solution, I'd love to read about it. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: My patch is now a part of Postgres v10+.

You can read about how this works here [3](https://www.thatguyfromdelhi.com/2017/03/using-pgdumpall-with-aws-rds-postgres.html).

Earlier, I had also posted a working solution posted to my [Github](https://github.com/robins/postgres/tree/aws_postgres_support) account. Then, you'd need to compile the binary and use that however, with the patch now a part of Postgres v10+, any pg_dumpall since that version now supports this feature.

You can read some more detailed inner workings [here](http://www.thatguyfromdelhi.com/2016/12/custom-pgdumpall-now-works-with-aws.html).

Comment: Hi Robbins.  That looks very impressive.  Thank you for sharing it.  It might take me some time to make way through it.  So, this code scripts out the pg_dumpall manually and stores in a .sql file?  Does it make any changes to the source database, or is it just mocking up the code for you to execute on the target database?

Comment: (1) Its a WIP. (2) It doesn't make *any* changes to the DB (otherwise the whole exercise is moot (3) I'll probably posting an update on my blog soon, but sadly that's the most I can offer right now. ThatGuyFromDelhi.com. Thanks

Comment: Have updated the URL (in the above answer) to a Branch instead of a commit. Should work in most databases on AWS RDS postgres. Let me know if this is not so.